# Why does this C++ code cause a runtime error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, constructor, runtime-error

I get the following error when I try to run this code in Visual Studio 2010:

> > Unhandled exception at 0x012c23d3 in matrix.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccd0.

Here's the code:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class matrix : public vector<vector<char>> {
  public:
    matrix(int x, int y) {
        this->resize(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
            this[i].resize(y);
        }
    }
};

void main() {
    matrix mat(10, 10);
}
```

I'm trying to create a `matrix` class that expands on the `vector<vector<char>>` type by adding built-in matrix manipulation functions. However, I can't get this constructor to run properly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ouch. Don't inherit publicly standard container. They don't have virtual destructor, you could end up in very ugly situations...

Comment: don't you want i < x in your loop?

Comment: Your constructor first resizes the object to be able to contain 10 vectors, and then resizes each of those to be able to contain 10 chars... however resize doesn't create those elements, it only makes room for them. You're trying to resize the child vectors that have not yet been created, no?

Comment: Okay--I see what you mean about the child vectors not being created yet. For some reason I couldn't assign `this[i]` to a new vector.

Comment: You couldn't assign this[i] to a new vector because `this` is a vector of vectors, and `new vector` creates a pointer to a vector.

Comment: What would have been the correct way to create that child vector, @mah? (Realizing of course that my implementation is flawed--just curious for learning purposed)

Comment: One option could be to let the matrix class be a vector of pointers to vector<char>, letting you assign the return of `new vector<char>` as you likely tried already. Another would be to make the assignments such as `(*this)[i] = *(new vector<char>(y));` -- dereferencing to get the actual vector rather than its pointer. I'm concerned that the second option could easily lead to a memory leak though. In your specific case of a 2 dimensional array of chars, the best option is to simply allocate a member variable `char *data = new char[x*y];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't inherit publicly from standard containers: They aren't meant for it, having no virtual destructor. Even if you never intend for your derivation to be deleted by base class pointer, someone will come along and do it years from now, not realizing the pitfall. Inheriting from standard containers `protected`ly or `private`ly is fine because you can't attempt to polymorphically destroy your child.

Then your problem is twofold: `i < y` instead of `i < x` in your loop condition and `this[i]` instead of `(*this)[i]` which would cause it to use the parent class `operator[]` rather than the builtin `[]` that operators on arrays and pointers.

BUT your entire constructor could be done away:

```
matrix(int x, int y) : vector<vector<char> >(x, vector<char>(y)) { }
```

Comment: mmm. I liked my version better (with the typedef). Anyways, I've blasted it for a proper, non-inheriting demo

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not improper to derive from classes that do not have a virtual destructor as long as the derived classes are never handled via polymorphic means.

Comment: _Then your problem is i < y instead of i < x in your loop condition._ -- that's a potential problem, but not a problem in his immediate case since for his failing test, x == y == 10.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to do the constructor correctly. I'll try some of these suggestions for creating a better class that doesn't use standard containers.

Comment: I am agreed with @mah that's not the actual problem... The actual problem is that this[i] is not the vector in position i but the pointer address + i bytes

Comment: How would I reference the vector in position i, @Pedrom?

Comment: @Praetorius I posted an answer with an example :)

Comment: What if I do this: http://ideone.com/72wI4Q


The base class destructor can't be accessed because the base class is inherited as "protected", but the `[]` operator *can* be accessed because I declared it in the `public:` section. Right?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest rewriting this as follows: **http://ideone.com/mzsE8e**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
using matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

template <typename T>
matrix<T> make_matrix(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    return { x, typename matrix<T>::value_type(y) };
}

int main() {
    auto mat = make_matrix<char>(3, 5);


    // for demonstration only:
    for (auto& row : mat)
    {
        for (auto& cel : row)
            std::cout << (int) cel << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides all other recommendations your problem is on the line:

```
this[i].resize(y);
```

Since it is not doing what you want. It is moving the pointer of this by i bytes. Since you want to access the [] operator you need to dereference the pointer:

```
(*this)[i].resize(y);
```

Comment: I noticed the discrepancy and deleted my comment as you were posting yours. However something doesn't quite look right to me about your suggestion... perhaps (*this)[i].resize(y) is more correct?

Comment: @mah yeah I noticed and deleted my comment too. Oops you are right... transcription typo :) Thanks.. just edited it.

Comment: Oh--wow. I had tried `*this[i].resize(y)` and it wouldn't compile, but your recommendation of `(*this)[i].resize(y)` works fine. Is this because it's interpreting the former as `*(this[i].resize(y))`?

Comment: @Praetorius I think the compiler would interpret *this[i].resize(y) as (*this[i]).resize(y) and wont compile since this[i] is not a vector (or even an object)

Comment: +1 you should consider `this->operator[](i)` in readability edge cases like this. Of course, better yet: use `at(i)` :) (or not abuse inheritance in the first place...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
class matrix : public vector< vector< char > >
{
public:
    matrix(int x, int y)
    {
        vector< char > _val(y, 0);
        this->resize(x, _val);
    }
};
```